# Infix to postfix conversion (using stack)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote a program to convert infix to postfix operation using stack in c++. But on running this I am getting Segmantation fault. 
Please help me know my mistake. I am not able to know.

I have used the algorithm as below:

```
1. Scan the infix expression from left to right.
2. If the scanned character is an operand, output it.
3. Else,
…..3.1 If the precedence of the scanned operator is greater than the precedence of the operator in the stack(or the stack is empty), push it.
…..3.2 Else, Pop the operator from the stack until the precedence of the scanned operator is less-equal to the precedence of the operator residing on the top of the stack. Push the scanned operator to the stack.
4. If the scanned character is an ‘(‘, push it to the stack.
5. If the scanned character is an ‘)’, pop and output from the stack until an ‘(‘ is encountered.
6. Repeat steps 2-6 until infix expression is scanned.
7. Pop and output from the stack until it is not empty.
```

The code is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

int preceedence(char x) {
    switch(x) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
            break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;
            break;
        case '^':
            return 3;
            break;
        return -1;
    }
}
// A utility function to check if the given character is operand
bool isOperand(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
}
int infixToPostfix(string str) {
    stack<char> operators;
    string output;
    for(string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
        if(isOperand(*it)) {
            output += *it;
            cout << *it;
        } else if(*it == '('){
            operators.push(*it);
        } else if(*it == ')') {
            while(!operators.empty() && operators.top() != '(') {
                output += operators.top();
                operators.pop();
            }
            if(!operators.empty() && operators.top() != '(') {
                cout << "Invalid Expression";
                return -1;
            } else {
                operators.pop();
            }
        } else { // An operator is encountered.
            while(!operators.empty()) {
                if(preceedence(*it) <= preceedence(operators.top())) {
                    output += operators.top();
                    operators.pop();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            operators.push(*it);
         }
    }
    while(!operators.empty()) {
        output += operators.top();
        operators.pop();
    }
    cout << output<< endl;
    return 0;
}



int main() {
    string str;
    //getline(std::cin, str);
    str = "(1+2)*5";
    cout << "The postfix conversion of the infix stream is : "<< endl;
    infixToPostfix(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the data that you used to duplicate the issue?  You should hardcode that data into the program instead of giving us a call to `getline`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie See the edit. The input string was "(1+2)*5"

Comment: Where is your check for an empty stack here: `else { operators.pop(); }`?  In addition, didn't your compiler warn you about `precedence()` possibly not returning a value, thus invoking undefined behavior?

Comment: thanks @PaulMcKenzie. The empty check over it solved the problem.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not the only problem.  Check your `precedence()` function and what it does if `x` matches none of those characters in the `switch` statement.

Comment: Ya I have checked. the return -1 should be outside the switch.